# jQuery click event is triggered only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

In my page I have two different forms. I want user to see one form at a time and switch between the forms when user clicks a link.

To achieve that, I included a link in both the forms and binded the click event so that when it's clicked user sees the form other than what's already visible.

The problem is that I couldn't implement that in jQuery.
Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-6 loginPanel">
  <div class="panel panel-default myFormContainer">
    <div class="panel-heading myPanelHeadingContainer">
      <h3 class="panel-title">
        Login
        <span class="flipper">
          <a href="#">Flip</a>
        </span>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="authCode">Authentication Code</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="authCode" placeholder="Auth Code">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 registerPanel">
  <div class="panel panel-default myFormContainer">
    <div class="panel-heading myPanelHeadingContainer">
      <h3 class="panel-title">
        Register
        <span class="flipper">
          <a href="#">Flip</a>
        </span>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="newAuthCode">New Authentication Code</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="newAuthCode" placeholder="New Auth Code">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="clientSecret">Client Secret</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="clientSecret" placeholder="Client Secret">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

In the HTML code above, I have wrapped the link inside a `span` and given it the class `flipper`.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.registerPanel').first().hide();
  var flipper1 = $('.flipper').first();
  var flipper2 = $('.flipper').get(1);

  flipper1.click(function () {
    $('.loginPanel').first().hide();
    $('.registerPanel').first().show(400);
  });

  flipper2.click(function () {
    $('.registerPanel').first().hide();
    $('.loginPanel').first().show(400);
  });
});
```

In the code above, I intentionally binded the click event to the `span` element assuming that when something inside it is clicked, the click event for `span` will fire.

Also, `flipper1` and `flipper2` two are the two variables holding reference to two `span` elements relating to two different forms.

Initially, when no clicks happen and no events fire, the `loginPanel` is expected to be visible (that's why I hid `registerPanel`).
When I click the Flip link, it hides the `loginPanel` and shows `registerPanel` as expected but when I click the link in `registerPanel`, nothing happens (i.e. I can't go back to `loginPanel`).

Can someone tell what's wrong and if possible, please suggest a good fix. Thanks!

Comment: try assigning id to your flippers i.e. #flipper1 #flipper2

var flipper1 = $('#flipper1');
var flipper2 = $('#flipper2');

Comment: Also, `hide()` may be removing the event listeners / handlers? You could try `detach()` / `appendTo()` ?

Comment: @AnandSiddharth that worked. Although I had to change all the styling I did for .flipper. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`.get()` method returns the DOM elements matched by the jQuery object, so that might be the reason that second click is not happening.

So, you can use `eq` selector here like:

```
$('.registerPanel').first().hide();
var flipper1 = $('.flipper:eq(0)');
var flipper2 = $('.flipper:eq(1)');

flipper1.click(function() {
  $('.loginPanel').first().hide();
  $('.registerPanel').first().show(400);
});

flipper2.click(function() {
  $('.registerPanel').first().hide();
  $('.loginPanel').first().show(400);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var flipper1 = $('.flipper').first();
var flipper2 = $('.flipper').last();
```

the problem is with the `.get(1)`, the event doesn't get added to it as `.get()` returns DOM elements, but `.first()` and `.last()` return jQuery objects.